# Korn Shell - How can I make “Press any key to continue”

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am writing korn shell script. I need to put funtionality called "Press any key to continue" to execute rest of the script.How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean, when you install the .deb package, it prompt user to install it [Y/n]:? like that

Comment: No, I don't want to use any package. Is it possible to implement it using `read` command? Instead of hitting [Enter] , I want it to accept any key and continue

Answer (score 2):

**You can use read command:**

```
read -n1 -r -p "Press space to continue..." key

if [ "$key" = '' ]; then
    # Space pressed, do something
    # echo [$key] is empty when SPACE is pressed # uncomment to trace
else
    # Anything else pressed, do whatever else.
    # echo [$key] not empty
fi
```

**This is very simple script.**

```
   #!/usr/bin/ksh 

    echo "First Method"
    read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."

    # insert echo here for cleaner output
    echo

    echo "Second Method"
    echo "Press any key to continue..."
    read -s -n 1 any_key
    echo "Now exiting"
    exit 0
```

### **Information about the read command:**

To get input from the keyboard, you use the read command. The read command takes input from the keyboard and assigns it to a variable. Here is an example:

```
echo -n "Enter some text > "
read text
echo "You entered: $text"
```

Comment: -p prompt.
    Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting
    to read any input. The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a
    terminal. I suggest you read the manpage of read command.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is the command for input (usually form terminal). There is (nearly) no way around the `<Enter>`, its the way to tell read to start processing the input.

If you want to start processing after whatever keystroke,   you have to dive deep into terminal settings via `stty`, changing to raw mode and .....

And it is likely your terminal is in foul mood when you are coming out of that.
The effort to avoid side effects is usually not worth the effect.

Think about, you changed the terminal mode, waiting for a keystroke, do you  allow Ctrl-C, backspace, ESC, ...  to be keystroke or do they need special handling? You changed the terminal mode, you are respnsible now. How to set the terminal to a sane state if the process has been killed , ....

If you are up for a big challenge, go for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand why my post was deleted. Here I go again.

What I did is to create a function 'readOne' and call it when needed.

```
readOne () {
tput smso
echo "Press any key to return \c"
tput rmso
oldstty=`stty -g`
stty -icanon -echo min 1 time 0
dd bs=1 count=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
stty "$oldstty"
echo
}
```

Here is the explanation from the author :

> The tty driver controls how input lines that you type are delivered to programs. Normally a tty driver will wait until a complete line is available. It also handles stuff like backspace so that program doesn'y need to. The stty command lets you change the way the tty driver works. "stty -a" will display all of the settings. You should do that to see what's available.
>
> "stty -g" displays all of the settings too. But it's encoded and you can't understand the output. But you can save the output and feed it back into the stty command. So:
>   oldtty='stty -g'
>   stty $oldstty
>   will save and restore the original settings of the tty driver.
>
> stty -icanon -echo min 1 time 0
>   is setting some options in the tty driver. -icanon turns off all special character processing. Now a backspace will be passed to the program rather than being processed. And a carriage return won't terminate a line. So now min and time control when a read has finished. "min 1" says we need at least one character. "time 0" means that we won't wait a while before completing a read. So each read from the program may return after just one character.
>   the -echo just turns off echo. I would not have done that.
>   dd is a program that is prepared to read data that is not organized into lines. This dd will read one block (count=1) of data. And that block will be one character in length (size=1). So the dd will read one character and return to the script.
>   The final echo moves the cursor to the next line.